# Zend Framework class not loading in Ubuntu

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have ported my Zend Framework application to a different server. It's a Zend Framework application version `2.3.*`

Now when going to this url http://calendar.app/calendar I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Calendar\Controller\CalendarController' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/calendar/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170`

My CalendarControler lives in my calendar module which is loaded like

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Calendar' => 'Calendar\Controller\CalendarController',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'calendar' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/calendar',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'calendar',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

I tried

`composer clear-cache
composer dump-autoload`

But this didn't help.
How could I fix this.

Comment: Calendar\Controller\CalendarController is the slashes in correct direction? and i think you need supply whole path

Comment: This error would seem to indicate one of three things -- either you don't have a file named `Calendar/Controller/CalendarController.php` in your path, you have the file but the class name defined in it doesn't match, or you haven't registered an autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Calendar` declaration inside the array is wrong. You need to use the full name in the array in order for Zend to find the class.

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Calendar\ControllerCalendar' => 'Calendar\Controller\CalendarController',
    ),
    'alias' => array(
        'Calendar' => 'Calendar\ControllerCalendar',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'calendar' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/calendar',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'calendar',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Aside fro this error. Consider using controller factories if your class has hard dependancies or you are using the service manager like `$this->getServiceLocator()` inside your controller. :)